# Setting container location using JClouds Location API

Tags: rackspace, jclouds

I am using JClouds to abstract over various cloud providers, including Rackspace.

I am using the BlobStore from JClouds to store files, their API suggests that I can create a container in a specific (provider dependent) Location using:

```
context.getBlobStore().createContainerInLocation(location, "containerName");
```

However, how am I supposed to get the location variable (of interface type Location)?

For example, RackSpace supports Dallas or Chicago as the Location of a container. So I would like to do something like this:

```
 Location dallas = ....; // Get location that points to "US-IL"
 context.getBlobStore().createContainerInLocation(dallas, "container");
```

The 'magic' string US-IL was taken from [the source](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/providers/cloudfiles-us/src/main/java/org/jclouds/rackspace/cloudfiles/CloudFilesUSProviderMetadata.java).

I tried using this:

```
 context.getBlobStore().listAssignableLocations();  // Only contains a single default location
 context.getBlobStore().listAssignableLocations()[0].getParent(); // Not sure what this refers to, scoped at PROVIDER level
```

Anyone that can shed some light on how I should be using this?

Related question: [JClouds for Azure Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146953/jclouds-for-azure-blob) (not applicable, because the answer is Azure specific. Which did not require the location...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible in jclouds 1.8.0 and above.

```
RegionScopedBlobStoreContext blobStoreContext = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(PROVIDER)
        .credentials(username, apiKey)
        .buildView(RegionScopedBlobStoreContext.class);
BlobStore blobStore = blobStoreContext.getBlobStore(REGION);
```

Comment: Yes, I found as much in the source code. I checked for Atmos (Ninefold) as well, but location isn't supported there either. It looks like the enter Location API is not implemented for the BlobStore.

Comment: We have a start on it at [openstack-swift](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-labs-openstack/tree/master/openstack-swift) but we still have a ways to go.